# Replace multiple foreign characters in multiple tables after collation change

Tags: mysql, wordpress, collation

I have a WordPress site, where the collation was set to `utf8_unicode_ci`  and I had to use lithuanian characters `(Ą ą Č č etc.)`. All of these characters where encoded and saved like following `(Ä„ , Ä… , ÄŒ , Ä etc)`.

I have since changed to collation to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`, and all of the new records are saved and displayed correctly. However, all of the old records are displayed exactly as they appear in the database `(Ä„ , Ä… , ÄŒ , Ä etc)`.

How can I replace multiple characters in multiple tables to match current collation?

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

**EDIT with more information**

Basically the site was running on an unsopported server. In the database server section of phpMyAdmin I can see the following information:

```
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Software: MySQL
Software version: 5.1.58-1~dotdeb.0-log - (Debian)
Protocol version: 10
User: srvmtb_mtbWP@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
```

Here is the the create table of an old table (most of fields were removed for clarity):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_posts` (
  `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_content` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `post_title` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `post_name` (`post_name`(191)),
  KEY `type_status_date` (`post_type`,`post_status`,`post_date`,`ID`),
  KEY `post_parent` (`post_parent`),
  KEY `post_author` (`post_author`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Here is the example of `INSERT` generated on db export:

```
INSERT INTO `wp_posts` (`ID`, `post_content`, `post_title`) VALUES
(1, 'Tomas TomĆ„ā€”nas', '');
```

So I had exported the whole database like this an imported into a newer server. Here is the database server information:

```
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MariaDB
Server version: 10.0.25-MariaDB - MariaDB Server
Protocol version: 10
User: woalba@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
```

After updating, I had run the following query for every table:

```
ALTER TABLE wp_posts CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Right now every new record is inserted and retrieved with correct characters in place without any problem, however all of the old records are retrieve with the strange characters like `Ć„ā€”`.

If there is any other important information that I should provide - just ask.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT with SHOW CREATE TABLE**

```
    CREATE TABLE `wp_posts` (  `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_author` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
 `post_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 
 `post_date_gmt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 
 `post_content` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,  
`post_title` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,  
`post_excerpt` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, 
 `post_status` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'publish',
  `comment_status` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'open', 
 `ping_status` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'open', 
 `post_password` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
 `post_name` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
 `to_ping` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, 
 `pinged` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,  
`post_modified` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 
 `post_modified_gmt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 
 `post_content_filtered` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, 
 `post_parent` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
 `guid` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
 `menu_order` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
 `post_type` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'post',
  `post_mime_type` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
 `comment_count` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`), 
 KEY `post_name` (`post_name`(191)),  
KEY `type_status_date` (`post_type`,`post_status`,`post_date`,`ID`),  
KEY `post_parent` (`post_parent`),  
KEY `post_author` (`post_author`)) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=6394 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

**EDIT with SELECT HEX (post_title)**

```
real title is "gegužės 9, 2016 @ 10:16 PM"
post_title = geguÅ¾Ä—s 9, 2016 @ 10:16 PM
HEX(post_title) = 4F7264657220266E646173683B2067656775C385C2BEC384E280947320392C203230313620402031303A313620504D
```

Comment: NO!  Let's fix the table declaration and data, instead.  Please provide what you had, plus the steps you took to get into this mess.

Comment: Please provide `SELECT col, HEX(col) ...` for an "old record" and for a "new record".  That will help us unravel it.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the connection parameters.

Comment: I have updated the question with more information. If there is anything else that needs to be provided - just ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible answer:

The generated `INSERT` was output from `mysqldump`?  And it did not include the option `--default-character-set=utf8`?

(I think, without proof, that that caused the problem.)

Do you now have a table with some 'correct' letters and some "Mojibake" (such as `Ä„`)?  And you want to find and fix the Mojibaked rows?

`WHERE col LIKE '%Ä%'` might find it.  However, `TomĆ„ā€”nas` does not follow the same pattern, so I am worried that it is not sufficient.

I don't see how to untangle Ć„ā€” -- it may be two or even three steps.

What `CHARACTER SET` was the table before utf8 or utf8mb4?  Usually Mojibake involves incorrect conversion between some other charset (such as latin1) and utf8.  I tried latin2, latin5, and latin7; none seemed to work.

Please provide the `SELECTs` I requested.

I'm not giving up, but this is quite a challenge.

**Possible Fix**

(I say "possible" because this may or may not be the complete and correct answer.)

First, test it:

```
SELECT ID,
        CONVERT(BINARY(CONVERT(post_title USING latin1)) USING utf8)
    FROM wp_posts;
```

to see if it works well for `post_title` for all the rows.  If you like the output, then...

```
UPDATE wp_posts
    SET post_title =
        CONVERT(BINARY(CONVERT(post_title USING latin1)) USING utf8)
```

Evidence:

```
mysql> SELECT CONVERT(BINARY(CONVERT('geguÅ¾Ä—s 9, 2016 @ 10:16 PM' USING latin1)) USING utf8);
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| CONVERT(BINARY(CONVERT('geguÅ¾Ä—s 9, 2016 @ 10:16 PM' USING latin1)) USING utf8)      |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| gegužės 9, 2016 @ 10:16 PM                                                            |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, let me answer your questions now. 

Yes, the `INSERT` was the output from mysqldump and it did not include the `--default-character-set=utf-8`.

Correct, all of the old records are "Mojibake". Keep in mind, that they are Mojibakes in the old database as well. However, WordPress managed to convert them to proper lithuanian characters in the front end, before changing the charset. Because of that administrator did not bother to fix the issue and that is why we have loads of Mojibaked records.

Comment: There are a total of 16 upper and lower case character and each of them is shown as a different Mojibake.

The old database is utf8 and the new one is utf8mb4.

I will generated `SELECTs` that you have requested straight away and add them to the question.

Thank you once again.

Comment: What are the 16 characters?  utf8 and utf8mb4 work identically for all Western/Eastern European characters.  (Only Chinese, Emoji and a few other things have differences.)  That is, utf8/utf8mb4 was not part of the problem, nor is it relevant to the solution.

Comment: There 16 lithuanian characters which used to get saved as Mojibakes.

So what could have caused the problem then? And what be the way to solve it?

Comment: I have added the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` statement. Unfortunatelly, I did not understand what `SELECT col, HEX(col) ...` means.

Comment: I see 18:  `ĄČĘĖĮŠŲŪŽąčęėįšųūž`.

Comment: Let's say that the post with ID=3 has a title with `post_title` that _should be_ 'ĄČĘ'`.  Then I would like to see what you get from running `SELECT post_title, HEX(post_title) FROM wp_posts WHERE ID=3;`...

Comment: Correctly encoded as utf8 (or utf8mb4), it would say `ĄČĘ  C484 C48C C498`.  With Mojibake it _might_ say  `Ä„ÄŒÄ˜  C384 E2809 EC384 C592 C384 CB9C`.  Or, it might say something else.  Since there are many directions the mangling of the characters _could_ have gone, I want to see the hex in order to be certain of the direction to go.

Comment: `TomĆ„ā€”nas` has me stumped; maybe the hex would uncover something I am not thinking of.

Comment: `Ä„ , Ä… , ÄŒ , Ä` is exactly what I would expect in your first example.

Comment: Another, easy, test to perform:  With Mojibake text showing in the browser, do `ALT > View > Encoding` and see whether it is showing `Western` or `utf8`.  Then change to the other encoding.

Comment: Thanks a lot for not backing off of this trouble :) I have updated the question with SELECT HEX, hopefully that will help as well.

Comment: I added 'Possible fix'.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot, it actually works! Can I give a bonus here on SO? :)